# «Inconsistent Line Ending» in Visual Studio when editing from outside VS

Tags: visual-studio

I have written a script that checks out a file that changes a value in a line of a file and checks in the code. But after that when I open the file it gives me a popup

> Inconsistent line Ending
>
> The Line endings in the following file are
>   not consistent. Do you want to normalize the line ending.

Is there a way to avoid this? When I compare I do not see any difference. Would it cause any issues for compiling the program?

Comment: Most likely it's an encoding issue.  May we see the code?

Comment: As @Hi-Angel says. Plus, your script could check the line-ending characters used in the file and make sure that the new text you insert has the same characters. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: You have to accept an answer, either ask for details if it's unclear.

Comment: ⁻¹,  because the question clearly answered, but for two months you still neither accepted the answer, nor asked for more info; but I see you have been in the site.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you met is about a different endline encoding. I bet that the script you wrote for changing files insert a line ending like `\n`. It is a «*nix» notation, usually also called «LF». Windows notation for a newline for some *(I guess historic)* reason requires two characters, it is called «CR/LF». That is, you need in your script insert not just the `\n`, but `\r\n`. Just for you interest, there is also just «CR» notation, i.e. `\r` — it was used in older MACs.

The message you see complains about the fact, that a file now have different line endings. That is, every line in the file was most likely in «CR/LF», and now there's a line in another notation. You ought to have the same line notation throughout the file, with disregard would it be «Unix», «MAC», or «Windows» one.

> When I compare I do not see any difference.

It is non-printable characters, and usually not shown in text-diff utilities.

> Would it cause any issues for compiling the program?

Hardly it could cause any compile problems. Anyway, now you know what is the problem, and how to fix it.

Comment: `\r` is no longer used on Mac (it was on older Macs, but that is already 10+ years ago iirc).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel ah, I didn't knew, thank you very much! I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code i used in powershell to

```
$enc = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding( $false ) # required to save the file with UTF8 Without BOM
$wrt = New-Object System.XML.XMLTextWriter( $phyicalPath, $enc )
$wrt.Formatting = 'Indented'
$webconfig.Save($wrt)    
$wrt.Close()
(Get-Content $phyicalPath)|Set-Content -Path $phyicalPath -Force # normalize line ending
```